q-difference equation for the basic hypergeometric series
Basic hypergeometric series is q-analogue of generalized hypergeometric function.
Question: what is the $D_q$ (q-difference) equation for the basic hypergeometric series ? (Which is q-analogue of the differential  equation for generalized hypergeometric function - see snapshots below ).
I remember seeing it somewhere - but cannot find again, and my hardcopy of Gasper-Rahman is not with me.

PS
For the case JUST  hypergeometric series it is (e.g.
https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9403216):


The differential equation (NOT q-analog) for generalized hypergeometric function
is on Wikipedia (my question is about q-analog of that) :


For some particular cases of orthogonal polynomials here:
(q)-Laguerre polynomials


or in the other form:

From: The Askey-scheme of hypergeometric orthogonal polynomials and its q-analogue
Roelof Koekoek Ren´e F. Swarttouw
https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9602214

Here some q-derivatives with respect to PARAMETERs
https://www.m-hikari.com/ijma/ijma-password-2009/ijma-password33-36-2009/ghanyIJMA33-36-2009.pdf
q-Derivative of Basic Hypergeometric Series
with Respect to Parameters
Hossam A. Ghany
See also:
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0550321319303979
Derivatives of any Horn-type hypergeometric functions with respect to their parameters
Author links open overlay panel
Vladimir V. Bytev a b
,
Bernd A. Kniehl..
And many other papers on that topic

q-Bessel functions (all 3) , here are q-difference eq. page 6, there are also many lovely formulas on other pages: Connection problems on higher order linear q-difference equations
Takeshi Morita, Osaka University https://perso.math.univ-toulouse.fr/jisom/files/2013/04/19apr13morita.pdf

some generalized q-difference equations stuied here: https://www.emis.de/journals/SIGMA/2022/080/sigma22-080.pdf Connection Problem for an Extension
of q-Hypergeometric Systems
Takahiko NOBUKAWA

q-difference and prismatic cohomology: https://perso.univ-rennes1.fr/bernard.le-stum/bernard.le-stum/Documents_files/ams-ems-smf.pdf q-difference equations and prisms
(Congrès joint AMS-SMF-EMS)
Bernard Le Stum
(joint work with Michel Gros and Adolfo Quirós)

Here is an answer for the particular case (r,r-1) series. (Is there similar for the general case ?)
DUALITY RELATIONS FOR HYPERGEOMETRIC SERIES
FRITS BEUKERS AND FRED´ ERIC JOUHET
https://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~jouhet/duality-revised.pdf


See also: https://faculty.niu.edu/math_bowman/docs/contig.pdf
Section 2
